# modifying this jquery poll script to accept numerical input instead of multiple choice

Tags: jquery, mysql

I'm looking to put several polls on a website I'm working on, but I need the poll to ask one question, allowing the user to input numerical values into a text field, rather than selecting multiple choice.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-advanced-poll-jquery-plugin--net-3029

```
(function($) {

//define jPoll object with some default properties
$.jPoll = {
    defaults: {
        ajaxOpts: {
            url: "poll.php"
        },
        groupName: "choices",
        groupIDs: ["choice0", "choice1", "choice2", "choice3", "choice4"],
        pollHeading: "Please choose your favourite:",
        rowClass: "row",
        errors: true
    }
};

//extend jquery with the plugin
$.fn.extend({
    jPoll:function(config) {

        //use defaults or properties supplied by user
        config = $.extend({}, $.jPoll.defaults, config);

        //init widget
        $("<h2>").text(config.pollHeading).appendTo($(this));
        $("<form>").attr({
            id: "pollForm",
            action: config.ajaxOpts.url,
            method: config.ajaxOpts.type
      }).appendTo($(this));
        for(var x = 0; x < config.groupIDs.length; x++) {
            $("<div>").addClass(config.rowClass).appendTo($(this).find("form"));
            $("<input type='radio' name='" + config.groupName + "' id='" + config.groupIDs[x] + "'>").addClass("choice").appendTo($(this).find("form").children(":last")).click(function() {
                ($(".error").length != 0) ? $(".error").slideUp("slow") : null ;
            });
            $("<label>").text(config.groupIDs[x]).attr("for", config.groupIDs[x]).appendTo($(this).find("form").children(":last"));
        }
        $("<div>").attr("id", "buttonRow").addClass(config.rowClass).appendTo($(this).find("form"));
        $("<button type='submit'>").text("Vote!").appendTo("#buttonRow").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            //record which radio was selected
            var selected;
            $(".choice").each(function() {
                ($(this).attr("checked") == true) ? selected = $(this).attr("id") : null ;
            });

            //print message if no radio selected and errors enabled
            if (config.errors == true) {
                (selected == null && $(".error").length == 0) ? $("<p>").addClass("error").text("Please make a selection!").css({display:"none"}).insertAfter("#pollForm").slideDown("slow") : null ;
            }

            //add additional request options
            var addOpts = {
                type: "post",
                data: "&choice=" + selected,
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data) {

                    //add all votes to get total
                    var total = 0;
                        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                        total += parseInt(data[x].votes);
                    }
                    //change h2
                    $("div#pollContainer").find("h2").text("Results, out of " + total + " votes:");

                    //remove form
                    $("form#pollForm").slideUp("slow");

                    //create results container
                    $("<div>").attr("id", "results").css({ display:"none" }).insertAfter("#pollForm");

                    //create results
                    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {

                        //create row elment
                        $("<div>").addClass("row").attr("id", "row" + x).appendTo("#results");

                        //create label and result
                        $("<label>").text(config.groupIDs[x]).appendTo("#row" + x);
                        $("<div>").attr("title", Math.round(data[x].votes / total * 100) + "%").addClass("result").css({ display:"none" }).appendTo("#row" + x);
                    }

                    //show results container
                    $("#results").slideDown("slow", function() {

                        //animate each result
                        $(".result").each(function(i) {
                            $(this).animate({ width: Math.round(data[i].votes / total * 100) }, "slow");
                        }); 

                        //create and show thanks message
                        $("<p>").attr("id", "thanks").text("Thanks for voting!").css({ display:"none" }).insertAfter("#results").fadeIn("slow");        
                    });                         
                }
            };
            //merge ajaxOpts widget properties and additional options objects
            ajaxOpts = $.extend({}, addOpts, config.ajaxOpts);

            //make request if radio selected
            return (selected == null) ? false : $.ajax(ajaxOpts) ;
        });

        //return the jquery object for chaining
        return this;
    }
```

});
})(jQuery);

I found an example jquery script that limits the kind of characters you can input into the text field, I'd really also like to limit the amount of characters you can input as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/HkEuf/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Numbers Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
});
```

This is slightly unrelated but still within the purview of this script. I'd also like to be able to output the highest received value to a particular cell within an html table located on the same page.

Thanks for your help in advance, I realize I'm asking quite a lot but I'm pressed for time and have absolutely no idea how to do this myself.

Comment: Look at `maxlength` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/4653/)

Try this update fiddle

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything

     var agetdata = $(this).attr("maxlength");
      limit_check($(this),  agetdata);
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
     function limit_check(limit_id,  num) {
                var txt_cnt = limit_id.val();
                txt_cnt = txt_cnt.substring(0, num);
            }
});
```